# Converting WMS data to vector

Tags: raster, wms, convert

For my class project, I need to analyze solar potential within a neighborhood at Wilhelmsburg. We need the Photovoltaic PV area, the amount of radiation taking into account the shading and the projected electricity yield of the PV system. I am using the website https://geoportal-hamburg.de/geo-online/#.  The only way was to check one by one to get the PV data. The problem is that there are 649 buildings. And doing it one by one is taking a lot of time. We can take data by using the WMS address.   But We got it as a raster file. It's good for visualization.  But not good for calculation.

It would be better if we can get this data as a vector file. Without vector file we cannot calculate. We need those data as attributes within a vector layer. Thus, you can do all sorts of calculation. Otherwise, we have to continue counting them which is too much time-consuming, because the data is very important.

Comment: A WMS service returns a **picture** of the data you can not reliably extract meaningful information from it - if you require actual data you must use a WFS or WCS endpoint to fetch actual data.

Answer (score 2):

In Network panel of browser debugger, you get https calls
like https://geodienste.hamburg.de/HH_WMS_Freiwilliges_Engagement?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&QUERY_LAYERS=freiwilligenagenturen&CACHEID=153183&LAYERS=freiwilligenagenturen&INFO_FORMAT=text%2Fxml&FEATURE_COUNT=1&I=50&J=50&CRS=EPSG%3A25832&STYLES=&WIDTH=101&HEIGHT=101&BBOX=568072.6863127096%2C5933801.333516213%2C568607.1443574355%2C5934335.7915609395

Change the beginning before `?` mark, `https://geodienste.hamburg.de/HH_WMS_Freiwilliges_Engagement` to `https://geodienste.hamburg.de/HH_WFS_Freiwilliges_Engagement` (part `HH_WMS` becomes `HH_WFS`)
and add at the end `?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetCapabilities`

Resulting URL would be `[https://geodienste.hamburg.de/HH_WFS_Freiwilliges_Engagement?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetCapabilities][2]`, you can either paste the URL in the browser to see list of layers (vector) and look if you find the layer you want or you can add in QGIS as a WFS service the URL `https://geodienste.hamburg.de/HH_WFS_Freiwilliges_Engagement`

PS: not German speaking guy so did not find the "right" layer, just took an example amongst the others